# Search url with a nested hash of parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I used to have a link that lead to a search action and carried certain parameters. This was the link (for example):

```
<%= link_to "search", discover_search_url(:category_id => 3) %>
```

A friend of mine refactored the site and did a fantastic job of it, but now the `category_id` is inside a parent hash called `pieces_search`. So instead of using `params[:category_id]` now I use `params[:pieces_search][:category_id]`.

My question is, how do I modify my link now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "search", discover_search_url(:pieces_search => {:category_id => 3}) %>
```